# How can I keep delimiter in using Regex?

Tags: regex, haskell

I'm new to Haskell.

I want to keep delimiter like `keepDelimsR` in using `regex`.

My Data file like this:

> 201306000300001AH0211123611234...(so many digit)...\n201306000300001B1F...(so many digit)...\n201306000300002AH021123611234...(so many digit)...\n201306000300002B1F...(so many digit)... repeat format: "so many digit" part is varying each size and different content.

```
splitRegex (mkRegex "2013[0-9]{11}AH021") myData
```

It works. But matched pattern is disappeared in result.

How can I keep matched string in result?

I tried several days, but still can't help this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"how do I keep delimiter" isn't proper english, and for a reason.

The only reason I say that is because you could say "how do I keep `the` delimiter", which is contradictory to a pattern since there could be multiple kinds, no?

Or you could say "how do I keep the delimiter(s)", which becomes more complicated and sorta answers your own question.

First capture a collection of the matches by looping through the match objects, then do the replace.

In short, there is no way to pull the match result out from a split function, so it has to be two seperate operations.

Comment: Thank you a lot. I find different way.